# asp:hyperlinkfield showing path rather than datatextfield

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a grid view that populates two columns. One with the name of a file and the other with a path that links to a pdf.

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Font-Names="Arial"
                Font-Size="11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#C2D69B" HeaderStyle-BackColor="green"
                AllowPaging="false" PageSize="10" OnRowDataBound="Grid_RowDataBound">
                <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="80%" DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundField>
                 <asp:hyperlinkfield headertext="PDF" datatextfield="PDF"   datanavigateurlfields="PDF"  datanavigateurlformatstring="" text="PDF" />                
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

I have tried renaming the field to say "PDF" rather than displaying that documents path. How can I have it be show "PDF" on the webpage rather than displaying the document path to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `DataTextField` attribute and it will use the `Text` attribute as link text.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="PDF" DataNavigateUrlFields="PDF" Text="Download PDF" />
```